# Make some regexps clickable (like URLs) and have them open URL

Tags: org-mode

I use org-mode to manage my notes and TODOs. At work, we use Jira to track bugs and development stories and I'd like to make this a bit easier.

I'd like to make all DEV-[0-9]+, BUG-[0-9]+ and some other terms behave like a normal URL, so that they are clickable (no need to make a explicit org-mode link) and that they open a URL with the matched term appended to them.

So DEV-1234 should be recognized as a link, and when I click on it Emacs should open the URL http://jira/browse/DEV-1234.

If possible, I'd like to have other terms with other endpoints as well.

Comment: You may want to look at bug-reference-mode

Answer (score 3):

One straightforward way is to

1. write a function inserting the desired buttons and then
2. hook it up with font-lock.

```el
(defvar jira-link-url "http://jira/browse/%s")

(defun jira-link-insert-buttons (beg end)
  (remove-overlays beg end 'type 'jira-link)
  (save-excursion
    (goto-char beg)
    (while (re-search-forward "\\_<\\(DEV\\|BUG\\)-[0-9]+\\_>" end t)
      (make-button (match-beginning 0)
                   (match-end 0)
                   'type 'jira-link
                   'action (lambda (button)
                             (browse-url (format jira-link-url (button-get button 'text))))
                   'follow-link t
                   'text (match-string 0)))))

(define-minor-mode jira-link-mode nil nil nil nil
  (cond
   (jira-link-mode
    (jit-lock-register #'jira-link-insert-buttons)
    (jira-link-insert-buttons (point-min) (point-max)))
   (t
    (jit-lock-unregister #'jira-link-insert-buttons)
    (remove-overlays (point-min) (point-max) 'type 'jira-link))))
```

Answer (score 2):

Another approach is the button-lock package.

```
(require 'button-lock)
(global-button-lock-mode)

(button-lock-set-button
 "DEV-[0-9]+"
 (lambda ()
   (interactive)
   (browse-url (concat "http://jira/browse/"
               (buffer-substring
            (previous-single-property-change (point) 'mouse-face)
            (next-single-property-change (point) 'mouse-face)))))
 :face (list 'org-link))
```

Answer (score 1):

An Org-native approach: use a link abbreviation.

```
[[jira-dev:1234][DEV-1234]]
```

To enable:

```
(add-to-list 'org-link-abbrev-alist 
    '("jira-dev" . "http://jira/browse/DEV-%s"))
```

> just correcting to -alist but adding this comment because edits must be at least 6 characters for some reason

And similarly for `BUG-*` etc.

With a suitably constructed `org-capture` template you could enter just "1234" in response to a prompt and then have the rest automagically filled in for you.

Comment: I think this is great for a beginner like me. May you suggest me where to put this function? `~/.emacs`?

Comment: But of course! :-)

Comment: i'm currently using `(setq org-link-abbrev-alist ...`, are you sure of your command `add-to-list`?

Comment: Not mine, it's built-in. `C-h f add-to-list RET` will tell you how it works. Probably less laborious, more concise, clearer and less error-prone than the `setq` approach.